# $U_1\oplus W=V$ and $U_2\oplus W=V$ but $U_1 \neq U_2$ where $U_1$ and $U_2$ are two subspaces of $V$.

Tags: vector-spaces

I am searching some counterexamples such that  $U_1\oplus W=V$ and $U_2\oplus W=V$ but $U_1 \neq U_2$  where $U_1$ and $U_2$ are two subspaces of $V$ and $V$ is a vector space except $\mathbb {R}^2 $.Is it possible in the space of matrices with real entries or in a polynomial space ?

Somebody please give me some hint.

Comment: Just think about $V$ as 3d space, $W$ the $xy$ plane, and $U_1$ the $z$ axis. Now let $U_2$ be any line passing through the origin, and is not contained in or perpendicular to $xy$ plane.

Comment: @TroyWoo's example works even in 2 dimension spaces.

Comment: Can you think to a basis $\mathbb{R}^3$ of the form $\{e_1,e_2,v\}$ where $v\ne e_3$?

Answer (score 1):

> To construct a counterexample for the assertion above, let $ \ V=\mathbb{R^2}$, let $U_1 = \left\{ (x,0) : x \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$, let $\ U_2 = \left\{ (0,y) : y \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$, and let $\ W = \left\{ (z,z) : z \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$. Then
>
> $\mathbb{R^2} = U_1 \oplus W$ and $\ \mathbb{R^2} = U_1 \oplus W$,
>
> as is easy to verify, but $U_1 \neq U_2$ .

From the solutions of *Linear Algebra Done Right* by Sheldon Axler.